# Get date from slot in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I got simplecomponent:

```
<template>
  <v-chip>
    <slot></slot>
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

and I use it like that:

```
  <formatted-date>2020-22-03</formatted-date>
```

how can I access the date given in the slot in the component?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate the given data, use PROPS instead slots.

```
<template>
  <v-chip>
    {{ date }}
  </v-chip>
</template>

<script>
...
props: ['date'],
...
</script>
```

And use it like that:

```
 <formatted-date date="2020-22-03"></formatted-date>
```

This way you can access it using `this.date` inside the component.
Read more at: [Official Docs - Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)